# Remove authorize.net from magento

Tags: admin, authorize.net

How to remove Authorize.net from Magento admin panel payment method.its not removing by deleting the file from folder.

Comment: Can you provide additional information? Have you cleared your cache after the steps you performed?

Comment: I already deleted authorize.net file frrom... app/design/adminhtml/default/layout/authorize.net & 
app/design/adminhtml/default/template/authorize.net and disabled it from backend ,but now also it is displaying on magento admin panel payment method page. And i already cleared cache many times

Comment: you should disable it from `System > Configuration > Payment Methods` rather than deleting file.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply disable the module.
create this file`app/etc/modules/Zzz_Zzz.xml` (use the same name. files are loaded alphabetically and this needs to be loaded last) with this content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
         <Mage_Authorizenet>
             <active>false</active>
         </Mage_Authorizenet>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Clear the cache and you are done

Comment: I already did this ,but this xml is working to disable moneybookers but not worked for Authorize.net

Answer (score 0):

You should disable it from `System > Configuration > Payment Methods` rather than deleting file.

If you still want to delete them, then you should also delete `module file` `app/etc/module/Mage_Authorizenet.xml` or edit it as this `<active>false</active>`.

But I don't recommend it to delete since it is core file, might affect other magento module.

Comment: deleted app/etc/module/Mage_Authorizenet.xml but no change .nw also it is visible on admin panel of magento.Is there any xml left which is creating this block on admin panel?

Comment: just set that to `<active>false</active>` and see if that helps. Wont it help to disable it from `system>config>payment methods`?

Comment: i used this code to make it disable <?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Authorizenet>
            <active>false</active> 
        </Mage_Authorizenet>
<Phoenix_Moneybookers>
            <active>false</active> 
        </Phoenix_Moneybookers>
        <!-- all other modules here -->
    </modules>
</config> its working for moneybooker but not for autorize.net

Comment: You should edit `Mage_Authorizenet.xml` file and set it `false`. In which file are you adding those codes?

Comment: changes to "false" still its displaying on admin panel.please give me proper steps to remove it.